# Making gVim behave with the English International keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-layout

I run gVim7.4 on Windows 7 with the English International keyboard layout. The keyboard layout works in a way so that pressing `  + `i` gives you `ì`.

In Vim insert mode that's the desired behavior. However it isn't in command mode where I effectively have to press ` + `<Space>` + `i` to go to the mark 'i'. I observed similar behavior for the caret `^` key. Pressing it makes vim wait for a vowel to be able to render `â`, `î` etc instead of directly going to be beginning of the line. It only goes there when I press `^` + `<Space>`.

In insert mode it's useful to be able to type `â`. It isn't in command mode and there it's completely useless to wait for another character.

Is there a way to get better behavior by editing the vimrc or writing a autohotkey script? Is there a way to make vim behave in command mode that still allows me to u?

Comment: Vim doesn't see any keycodes until you've completed the key chain (either as \`i or as \`<Space>), so there's little you can do in Vim. One thing you could maybe do is have AHK pick up on `<Esc>` and `i/a/A/o/O/` and start "insert mode" there when Vim is active. I have no idea if this is possible with AHK. Another fix is ditching AHK altogether and do this sort of stuff with Vim; which has the obvious drawback that it will work *only* in vim and not your other applications...

Comment: Posting answer because I don't have enough rep to comment. One workaround is to have both an international keyboard, and another keyboard. You can switch between them with win+space.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to avoid the `<space>`; that is why I use single quote instead, <kbd>'</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>, which is similar enough for me (doesn't move to the column, but to the beginning of the line).

You could also consider using another mark related movements, such as ]' and `].

If you find that you use <kbd>`</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> more often than <kbd>'</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> you could use a set of mappings to switch them:

```
nnoremap 'a `a
nnoremap `a 'a
```

(possibly using a loop similar to the one in [the capslock plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-capslock/blob/master/plugin/capslock.vim#L21)).

Or you could switch just ]' and `] and its counterparts (8 mappings instead of 52), directly or through some plugin such as [signature](https://github.com/kshenoy/vim-signature).

Comment: That doesn't help with <kbd>^</kbd> and <kbd>"</kbd> which seem more important than <kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>'</kbd>.